# How to access vue3 methods from event listener callback function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize, vuejs3

**Description**

In the [mounted()](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted) part of the component I add an event listener, which should call one of the methods.

**Code**

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    changeState: function(el) {console.log(el);}
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     
      //I'm using materialize.css carousel here
      //---------------------------------------
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
      M.Carousel.init(elems, {
        onCycleTo: function(el) {
          this.changeState(1);
         }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Problem**

I think there are two problems :

- this in onCycleTo refers to the function in onCycleTo and not to the methods part
- the eventListener gets added to the document, which is on a different scope, so this.changeState(1) refers to a global function (which does not exist)

**Possible Solution**

I think it might be possible to somehow address the methods from a global scope, but I don't know how. Any other solutions also welcome.

How can I resolve these Problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `this` to a global variable called `vm` then use to access the method :

```
 var vm=this;
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
      M.Carousel.init(elems, {
        onCycleTo: function(el) {
          vm.changeState(1);
         }
      });
    });
```

You could also try arrow function :

```
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
      M.Carousel.init(elems, {
        onCycleTo: (el)=> {
          this.changeState(1);
         }
      });
    });
```